# Model a system from a problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, physics

> At a distance of $48$ $m$, the front wheel of a car makes $10$
>   rotations more than the rear. If the circumference of the front wheel
>   was $40$ $cm$ larger and of the rear wheel $40$ $cm$ smaller, at the
>   same distance the two wheels would make the same number of rotations.
>   Find the circumference of each wheel.

I tried to model a system of equations by using $C=2\pi r$ but I am not sure how. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write that in equations:

$$4800cm=(N+10)C_{front} \quad 4800 cm=NC_{rear}$$

Where $N$ is the number of rotations and $C$ is the corresponding circumferences.

Then we have:

$$4800cm=N_x(C_{front}+40cm) \quad 4800cm=N_x(C_{rear}-40cm)$$

Where $N_x$ is the number of rotations now. From the last equation you get $C_{front}=C_{rear}-80cm$. You can do something similar with the first equation and you have a system of two equations with two unknowns.

Comment: But how do we remove $N$ and $N_1$ from the system? What can I do with the first equation to remove $N$?

Comment: You have $N=4800/C_{front}-10$, then you plug that in, and you get $4800=(4800/C_{front}-10)C_{rear}$.